# How to ensure that only allowed domains can call C# from Javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, com-interop, code-access-security

I noticed some samples flying around using `[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name="FullTrust")]` on classes used for `webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting`. Why is this used and not `LinkDemand`?

Also to put another layer of security, how can I ensure that only pages from allowed domains can execute code in the scripting object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the documentation to learn the differences between Demand and LinkDemand:
[SecurityAction Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.securityaction.aspx)

Here is a Microsoft support article with sample code that allows you to get the url of the web page hosting the ActiveX Control:
[How To Retrieve the URL of a Web Page from an ActiveX Control](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181678)

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the article. I suppose it is also possible to get the URL from the WebBrowser control.